# Create a Smart Playlist for iCloud Songs that have been downloaded Locally

Tags: itunes, itunes-match, smart-playlist

Is there a way to create a Smart Playlist in iTunes that will contain the songs in my library that have been downloaded locally?  I have to reduce the bandwidth used at my job but I can download files at night and I want to only play songs that are downloaded to my computer (plus I don't want to play all the songs I own :-)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the "location" parameter, and select "is on this computer", that will show only the ones downloaded—providing you don't have any other music.

This works for me, as I want to keep the storage on my MacBook Air to the minimum.

Comment: I just gave this a try and my playlist shows no tracks at all. The only tracks on this computer are ones that were downloaded via Match. It's Windows 7/32 bit and iTunes 10.5.2, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Jack I tried this on my PC was well (where the original library was matched from), and it did appear to work but did take about 2 minutes to run and hammered the CPU. Maybe leave it a couple of minutes and have another look.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work in the new Music.app as well. The playlist is empty. :-/

Comment: Working on macOS Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "Date Modified" parameter to "in the last [n] months". It worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: Has anyone verified this on macOS?

Comment: Not me, @JMY1000