# Local (downloaded) music on iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-match

On iTunes I set up a smart playlist to contain only downloaded music (iTunes Match) so that I can use it offline or when the connection has a very low quality (see for example [*Create a Smart Playlist for iCloud Songs that have been downloaded Locally*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34350/create-a-smart-playlist-for-icloud-songs-that-have-been-downloaded-locally))

I would like to achieve something similar on my iPhone.

I know that I can create a smart list on iTunes but the logic will refer to iTunes and not the iPhone. For example my "*downloaded music*" list is also present on iPhone but the songs are the one downloaded in iTunes not iPhone.

Did I miss something? Is there a way to create a similar list or to listen to local music only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you turn off iTunes match on your iphone?Maybe you should try to turn that off and you might need to also toggle the music player setting to local files only: go to Settings > Music and set the option for "Show all music" to OFF.

Comment: Hi, I never noticed the option. Turning iTunes Match off is not necessary. Disabling "Show all music" is enough (and switching it back on is a fast operation). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that a smart playlist will only sync the contents of the list to your phone, but not the logic of the smart list. So you probably cannot achieve your goal using a smart playlist. You correctly state that the smart playlist is evaluated on iTunes and not on the phone. This has has always been the behaviour of syncing any iPod/iPhone device with iTunes.

What you could do is to create a list with the music you would like to have  with you at all time and hit the download all button for this playlist on the phone when you have a good connection, e.g. wifi.

This probably not what you really want, but it's probably the next best thing.

Comment: Of course keeping a manual list (as a playlist) will work but this is exactly what I want to avoid.